# adding content to a getasync

Tags: c#

when using HttpClient and performing a PostAsync I am able to add a contract with HttpContent. for example

```
HttpContent content = new ObjectContent<myContractType>(MyContract, xmlFormatter);
var resp myClient.PostAsync(myUri,content).Result
```

when doing a GetAsync I am unable to pass a HttpContract object. That said do I need to just add the members of the contract in a query string or is there a better way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

The [nature](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) of GET requests does not provide a way to send large amounts of data to the server as might be done with a POST request. In practice, [a limited](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.1) amount of data can be sent in the form of headers or as part of a querystring.

There won't be a way to convert the XML data directly to a querystring, but this is an example of a request with a querystring:

```
var client = new HttpClient()
client.GetAsync(String.Format("http://service.example.com/api/{0}?foo=bar", id))
```